# How to get the time that it took to upload a file?

Tags: php, file-upload, time

In my web site I have a form with the

```
<input type="file"....>
```

In the action field I have "send_file.php". I get the file as postdata.

How to get the time that it took to upload the file? Is there a predefined variable that stores  this information??? Thanks!

Comment: What are you after? The time that it took to upload the file, or the time that the file was uploaded?

Comment: The time that it took to upload the file

Comment: @PeeHaa: Yeah, that's the only answer I could find.

Comment: Thank you! The "killer word" in google was "measuring" xD. Thank you!